# why log4j2 TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy is impacted by @Scheduled

Tags: log4j2, spring-scheduled

I configured log4j2  with Policy of TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, by which I expect that the log file can be rolled into a zip file every day at 00:00. But it doesn't happen.

```
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" ignoreExceptions="false" fileName="${log.file.dir}/aaa.log" filePattern="${log.file.dir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/aaa-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}:%4p %t (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="128 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

And when I add a class like as follows, the system creates a zip file every day at 3:15.

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Scheduled(cron="0 15 3 * * ?") //3:15 every day
    public void doSomething() {    
        logger.info("3:15 every day");
    }  
}
```

It is quiet weird that the log4j2 rollup mechanism is impacted by the Spring @Schedule annotation, isn't it? Anyone knows how I can avoid this from happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How often are you writing log records? The time based triggering policy only rolls over during the process of logging an event. The cron triggering policy uses a scheduler and performs the rollover from a thread so doesn't need an event to be logged to trigger it.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Your answer makes me understand my first question now, i.e. why the rollover doesn't occur at 00:00. And do you know why and how my config triggers the cron triggering policy? BTW, when I commented out the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy and observed that the rollover at 3:15 never occurs again.

Comment: Your configuration doesn't trigger the crown triggering policy as it isn't configured.

Comment: But I found it was rolling over every 3:15. Do you know what happened? Could you show me some example that may trigger the crown triggering policy? Thanks.